# How to transfer files & directories from Windows (virtual machine) to Linux

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machines, scp

I have Windows virtualbox virtual machine and i would like to transfer some files from it... i thought about using scp but i don't know what directory path should i write (i guess something like C:\something\something won't work from my Linux machine, will it?)

Edit:

- I don't want to use shared folders
- I would prefer guest (Windows) to not ftp/login/do anything with host (Linux)
- Could you add command line examples for methods you're writing about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to copy files from the guest system to the host system (or the other way around), the easiest solution is to set up a shared folder.  Check out the documentation for [VirtualBox Folder Sharing](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#sharedfolders).

If you already have ssh set up on your Linux machine and really want to use scp, you could always install [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) on your Windows virtual machine and use it, or use the SFTP client built in to [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/).

Answer (score 2):

There are some options you have:

- [Using shared folders](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=9372&start=0)
- [Using an alternative method on OSE](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Sharing_files_on_OSE)

Basically you have two options: using the [built-in folder sharing](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#sharedfolders) option, for which you'll need the Guest Additions installed and install from the [binary VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/VirtualBox_PUEL) (Not the [OSE community edition](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Editions)), or using the same approach you'd take with two physical computers, I.E., using the OS provided way to access. In your case, you could use either [Samba](http://www.samba.org), SSH or FTP.

If you are in a position to use Guest Additions, it's the easiest way, IMHO.

Comment: Could you comment what scp command should exactly look like in this case? How do I write Windows directory I want to copy to Linux? It has different directory structure than Linux

Answer (score 0):

You could use rsync, there are some Windows clients for it, such as Deltacopy. FTP is another simple option, or possible Samba.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest method would be to offline the VM and do a loopback mount of  the disk image under linux and copy the files.  That way you're avoiding the overhead of both the network and the VM execution.

Comment: You mean mount .vmdk? It's possible?

Comment: I seem to recall a "vmware-mount.pl" script (or something like that) from the days I had VMWare Workstation.  I assume they wouldn't have removed such a handy feature.

Answer (score 0):

I'd ftp the files from the windows system to the linux system.

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox supports virtual network drives. Open VirtualBox and there should be a "Virtual Network Drives" section. Simply add a folder (from linux), reboot your virtual machine and you should be able to access it via network neighbourhood (as you would "shared documents"). You can also map that to a network drive in windows.

Ex: I have my linux home folder mapped to the Z: drive.

Answer (score 0):

you can use WINSCP or FILEzilla client

Another menthod

you can mound the windows drive and copy and paste the file from LINUX to windows 
nautilus-connect-server